# Should I use NestedHorizalScrollview with 1000 child view?

Tags: android, android-studio

Should I use NestedVerticalScrollview Android with 1000 child view?

Answer (score 0):

Generating views in Android is generally fast, but if doing it a lot, it can get expensive.  Depending on the complexity of your itemView, this could get very expensive when scrolling in your case.  Unless you use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), whenever a view goes off screen that View will be destroyed, and each new item revealed by scrolling would have to be created anew. RecyclerView performs a recycling process on these views, so if each itemView has the same layout, it can reuse past views to present new information, thereby saving the time required for creating the view.
In your case, it sounds like all 1000 views would be created upon creation, which would probably take a fair amount of time to create the activity/fragment, and is a waste of resources, since only about a dozen could likely be displayed at any one time.

I suggest two things:

- Use a RecyclerView in place of the NestedVerticalScrollView. [Here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-recycler-view#0) is the official android codelab for RecyclerView in java. I'm sure you can find a kotlin version by search, if you're coding in kotlin.
- If your itemView (in recyclerView terminology this is a ViewHolder) is complex (aka nesting), use a constraintLayout within your ViewHolder. If it is a simple layout, you may use a LinearLayout, or if that does not provide the layout you desire, RelativeLayout. Even if you are just creating one TextView, you should use the ViewHolder pattern required by RecyclerView.

You could test out the performance of your scrolling behavior manually to see if you experience lag when scrolling in a ScrollView with a 1000 child views.  I suspect you would, even with the most basic itemView.

Also, do not use a RecyclerView within a ScrollView, this will not work well (as explained in the RecyclerView docs I linked in the first link above.)